# Stop publisher.cycleVideo() mirroring whe using rear camera in Opentok

Tags: opentok, tokbox

When I use publisher.cycleVideo() to switch cameras during a session, the video stream is always mirrored when using the rear camera. Is there any way to change the mirroring when using cycleVideo? I've tried the following code to switch the mirroring after cyclevideo to the rear camera but does nothing:

```
 mirror=true;  // Have tried with both mirror true and false
 constraints = {
        advanced: [{
            mirror: mirror
        }],
 };

 OT.getUserMedia().then((stream) => {
    populateDeviceSources(audioSelector, 'audioInput');
    populateDeviceSources(videoSelector, 'videoInput');
    stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.applyConstraints(constraints));
  });
```

Comment: Same error ... Did you solve it?

Comment: I ended up doing it by hand where I'd have the publisher send a message telling the subscriber if it was rear or front camera so subscriber would know which way to flip the image.

Comment: Is it possible to share part of your solution code?

Comment: My solution isn't very generic. Basically the subscriber puts the info on which camera is used into a database and then the publisher gets the info about the subscribers camera out of the database.